# Confused about proof that $G\bmod K$ is a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

THM: If $K$ is normal to $G$, then $G/K$ := {$aK : a \in G$}, called $GmodK$, is a group under the operation $aK$*$bK$ = $abK$, for all $a$, $b$ $\in G$.

Proof: using the normality of $K$ I was able to show the sets $aKbK$ and $abK$ are equal.

$aKbK = ${$akbk' : k,k' \in K$} = {$abk''k' : k'',k' \in K$} = {$abk''' : k''' \in K$}, since $K$ is normal.

My professor then writes: " $\phi : G \rightarrow G/K$, $\phi:a \longmapsto ah$ Is a homomorphism."

What I'm confused about: what is the map $\phi$? I showed $aKbK = abK$ which seems to me is the property $f(xy) = f(x)f(y)$, so yeah I can see how taking an element $a \in G$ and multiplying that coset with the coset of a another distinct element in $G$ will produce the coset of the product of those elements in $G$, and that is exactly a homomorphism? But what exactly do I say the map $\phi$ is? The map which induces a coset?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: 'Twas a typo, in my opinion: $\phi$  is defined  as $\phi(a)=aK$.

Comment: The correct notation of the map $\phi$ is $\phi:a\mapsto aK$.

Comment: Ohhh, that makes more sense now. Thanks!